# Perl to set/reset 8th bit on string

Tags: string, perl, bit-manipulation

Given a string, I want to

- set all chars from `A` fo `I`'s 8th bit on (`0x41` ~ `0x49` to `0xC1` ~ `0xC9`).
- reset all chars that has the 8th bit on to off.

Like,

```perl
$s='@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS';
$s1= join "", map { $_ |= 0x80 if /A-I/ } split //, $s;
$s2= join "", map { $_ &= ~0x80 } split //, $s1;
```

I think my above code is close, but it's not fully working.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

Firstly, the function that you pass to `map` has to return the desired value. Your code is setting `$_` to the desired value (which is fine, but unnecessary), but your code for `$s1` isn't returning the result, so you end up with an empty string. (Your code for `$s2` does return the result, so that one is fine in this respect, albeit written a bit strangely.)

Secondly, `/A-I/` is not the right regex. You meant to write `/[A-I]/`.

Thirdly, when Perl converts between strings and numbers (e.g. because you've called a bitwise operator with a string and a number), it does so by parsing the string to a number or formatting the number in base-10. For example, `'3' | 12` is equivalent to `3 | 12`, i.e. `15`, which then gets converted to `'15'` if necessary. That's not what you want; rather, you're interested in the ASCII/Unicode/byte value of characters in the string. For that sort of conversion, you need to use `ord` (character → number) and `chr` (number → character). But you can't write `chr(~0x80)`, because `~0x80` is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F` (assuming a 64-bit system), which is not a valid character code. Instead, you need to write `chr(0x7F)`, or `"\x7F"`, or else apply the `chr` *after* the bitwise operation, by writing e.g. `chr(ord($_) & ~0x80)`.

So, putting it together, you can write this:

```
$s = '@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS';
$s1 = join "", map { $_ | (/[A-I]/ ? "\x80" : "") } split //, $s;
$s2 = join "", map { $_ & "\x7F" } split //, $s1;
```

or this:

```
$s = '@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS';
$s1 = join "", map { $_ = chr((ord $_) | 0x80) if /[A-I]/; $_ } split //, $s;
$s2 = join "", map { chr(ord($_) & ~0x80) } split //, $s1;
```

or any of various other permutations along those lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive explanation where I went wrong. That's really a learning experience for me. Just FTA, when trying under `perl -d -e 0`, the first group of method, directly operate on chars using like `$_ & "\x7F"` give me `00000000000000000000` for both cases. Mine is perl5db.pl version 1.73 BTW.

Comment: @xpt: You're welcome! Re: behavior under `perl -d -e 0`: So interesting! I've never used the Perl debugger before, and I can't imagine why it behaves differently from just running the code directly. (That seems bad -- not how a debugger is supposed to behave! -- but it's very possible that I'm missing something.)

Comment: Ahh, indeed! running the code directly works perfectly! strange...

Answer (score 3):

Super fast solution:

```perl
my $out = $in =~ tr/\x41-\x49\x80-\xFF/\xC1-\xC9\x00-\x7F/r;
```

Comment: hmm... I gave it a try, to make all chars 8bit-set to make it simple -- `$s = '@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'; $s =~ tr/\x41-\x7F/xC1-\xFF/r; print $s`, but what printed is still `@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS`. what's wrong? What I really wanted to do was, `$_ = '@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS'; s{[A-I]+}{ tr/\x41-\x7F/xC1-\xFF/r}e`, but that's not working for me either, for the same reason I think. BTW, where can I read about the `/r` for the perl tr command? thx.

Comment: I don't have any man pages installed locally, so I checked out online helps like https://linux.die.net/man/1/perlop or http://web.mit.edu/perl5/www/man/perlop.html. Neither have the `/r`. Anyway, don't take `s{[A-I]+}{ tr/\x41-\x7F/xC1-\xFF/r}e` literally, it is the simplest example I can think of for conditionally replacement, i.e., search for a certain regexp (say `/[A-CF-IL-N]+/`) and replace the found string with their 8bit set. That's what I was trying to ask (I know, I wasn't able to generalize or give a better minimum example well). Thanks for the corrected answer. It solved my problem!

Comment: _"You are still replacing every occurence of a character. tr/// is the way to go for that"_ well, let me stress again that the conditionally replacement _only_ replace a _selected_ subset of string, not to blankly replace everything _unconditionally_. [A-CF-IL-N] is _just_ another _simplified_ example, as we are talking about principle here, not specific code, please don't take it literally.

Comment: OK, ok, I was talking in principle, if you need a concrete specific code, let's continue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128691/perl-to-call-the-tr-function-in-regex-replace

Comment: You're still off-topic.