# Perl to call the tr function in regex replace

Tags: regex, function, perl

How to properly use the `tr` result in regex replace?

```
echo 'E2"C"G | d3"G7" | F3"F" | A3"Dm" ' | perl -pe 's{".*?"}{$& =~ tr [\000-\177][\200-\377]r}ge;'
```

This works expectedly, however, when I tried to make use of the `tr` *result* to *construct* what I want,

```
echo 'E2"C"G | d3"G7" | F3"F" | A3"Dm" ' | perl -pe 's{".*?"}{$& =~ tr [\000-\177][\200-\377]r; " %$&% ";}ge;'
```

Things start to fall apart (the 8bit-set string is gone).
How to fix it please? (I tried to assign `$&` to a variable `$m` and use `$m` instead, but that didn't solve the problem)

Comment: What is the expected result? Btw, you are missing a `'` at the end of the second perl command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [$& variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$&) is read-only so the [tr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) operator cannot change it, which is why you use `tr` on it with `/r` modifier -- Then it *returns* the changed string (or the unchanged original if there were no changes) and *leaves the original intact*.

So assign that return to a variable and then use that variable

```
s{...}{ my $new = $& =~ tr[...][...]r; " %$new% " }
```

(`$new` may be same as old, `$&`)  
or compose your needed expression directly

```
s{...}{ " %" . $& =~ tr[...][...]r . "% " }
```

---

Given the parenthetical remark in the question

> (I tried to assign `$&` to a variable `$m` and use `$m` instead, but that didn't solve the problem)

yet another way is to first copy `$&` into a variable and then do as you please with it

```
{...}{ my $m = $&; $m =~ tr[...][...]; " %$m% " }
```

Note that now we *don't want* the `/r` modifier since that `$m` should be changed in-place (what wouldn't happen with `/r`)

Comment: I assume that the whole `tr` and regex with it does what is needed, by the question's statement that it "_works expectedly_"

Comment: _"Note that now we don't want the /r modifier since that $m should be changed in-place"_ That's exactly why my attempt failed. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that parenthetical comment was indeed added later :) when I thought it should be able to add more value to my question, :) I made many failed attempts actually. And I did tried to leave out the `/r` myself, but this time I was using the answer code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77123973/2125837. I.e., I did `echo 'E2"C"G | d3"G7" | F3"F" | A3"Dm" ' | perl -pe 's/".*?"/$m=$&; $m =~ tr|\x41-\x7F|xC1-\xFF|; " %$m% "; /ge;'` with and without the `/r`, but either case the results are not what I expected.

Comment: @xpt Alright, thanks for clarifying :)   I've removed my unneeded comments (about how it was good that you added that parenthetical remark, and which I hadn't noticed right away etc), as they are irrelevant to the Q-A as they stand at this point.  Just saying so that your last comment doesn't hang in midair :)